# Telerik-based DLL does not load, due to enhancer(?) issues

Tags: c#, msbuild, telerik, 32bit-64bit, telerik-open-access

I'm working on a C# solution, containing two projects, a client and a server.

Both are normally built using "Any CPU" (which means in my opinion) that they are build as 64-bit processes.

I'm facing different problems, most probably due to some enhancer issue, but I have no idea what this might be.

## Problem 1: older problem

While building the client, now I get the following error message:

> The specified assembly `'C:\Users\DDM\AppData\Local\Temp\_ptil_15736\Client_Program.Client.dll'` cannot be loaded. The problem might be that the enhancer runs in a .NET framework 2.0 vm and the assembly to enhance is a .NET 4.0 assembly or you are trying to enhance a x86 assembly in a 64 bit process or a x64 assembly in a 32 bit process. Please change the required version inside the enhancer.exe.config or venhance.exe.config or switch to 'Any CPU' for this project.

Now, some efforts:

- The mentioned directory `C:\Users\DDM\AppData\Local\Temp\_ptil_15736` does not even exist.
- Changing the build platform from "Any CPU" to "x86" sometimes makes the client work, sometimes not.

On the internet, I've found [following URL](https://www.telerik.com/forums/unable-to-compile-64-bit-assembly-that-contains-openaccess-orm), explaining something about 32-bit and 64-bit and some things about enhancers, whatever that might be.

Extra efforts:

In both my server application as my client application, I have quite some references to Telerik DLLs. Most have version "v4. ...", but `Telerik.OpenAccess` and `Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions` and `Telerik.OpenAccess.Runtime` have version "v2.0.50727".

As far as enhancers is concerned, this is the place where I find them:

```
C:\<all_projects>\packages\Telerik.DataAccess.Fluent.2013.3.1320.1\tools\enhancer\enhancer.exe.config
C:\<all_projects>\packages\Telerik.DataAccess.Fluent.2013.3.1320.1\tools\enhancer\venhance.exe.config
C:\<all_projects>\packages\Telerik.DataAccess.Fluent.2016.2.822.1\tools\enhancer\enhancer.exe.config
C:\<all_projects>\packages\Telerik.DataAccess.Fluent.2016.2.822.1\tools\enhancer\venhance.exe.config
```

(I have no idea which ones of those are actually used.)

All of those "*enhance*.exe.config" files have the same content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <!--The enhancer is compiled against .NET 4.0.-->
    <!--To be able to enhance an .NET 2.0 assembly please comment out the next line:-->
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Having a further look at the mentioned URL, there is following quote:

> Visual Studio starts the MsBuild.exe as 32-bit process

Well, I had a look the different "MSBuild.exe" files on my computer, and this is what I come up with:

```
C:\>dir /S /B "msbuild.exe"
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
C:\Temp_Folder\Default\MSBuild.exe
C:\Temp_Folder\NativeImage\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\MSBuild\3.5.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\MSBuild\3.5.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\MSBuild\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\MSBuild\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\MSBuild\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\MSBuild\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_msbuild_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.19041.1_none_fa6e7f402dbc0227\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_msbuild_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_3.5.19041.1_none_82a6b3679b68b331\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_msbuild_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15805.0_none_dc3886319c616739\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_msbuild_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15840.3_none_dc3389e19c65e13f\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_msbuild_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15805.0_none_0606cd4b5dabfc56\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_msbuild_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_4.0.15840.3_none_0601d0fb5db0765c\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_msbuild_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_10.0.19041.1_none_421bb61742382b2d\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_msbuild_b03f5f7f11d50a3a_3.5.19041.1_none_268817e3e30b41fb\MSBuild.exe
```

How can I know which one is used and how can I replace this by a 64-bit MSBuild.exe?

### Edit

While building my application, I see following warning, does anybody know what it means?

> MSBUILD : OpenAccess Enhancer warning : No persistent classes found. Is the metadata information missing?

1. What are persistent classes (in Telerik OpenAccess terminology)?
2. What is the mentioned metadata, and where and how can I read/write it?

## Problem 2: current problem

In my company, it is common to start with some kind of base classes, which have their objects stored in an SQL-server database. The last column in database of the base class is `voa_class`, showing the real class of the mentioned object.

Now I have a `Vehicles` base class and a subclass `<Company>.Viastore.Server.Domain.ViastoreSrm`, and in database I have a table, called  `Vehicles`, containing an entry with `voa_class` `<Company>.Viastore.Server.Domain.ViastoreSrm` and another table `ViastoreSrm`, containing an entry with the same `id` value as the one from the `Vehicles` table (both `id` fields being equal allow both entries to be linked to each other).

In source code, I have following line:

```
namespace <Product>.<Customer>.Server
{
    ViastoreSrm viastore = database.GetData<ViastoreSrm>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Although this is standard (this way of getting data from the Telerik Openaccess database is used for more than ten years), now I get the following `Exception`:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Type is enhanced and registered, but not available from the database class meta data. This can be caused by a wrong connection id or configuration.
Parameter name: type
Actual value was <Product>.Viastore.Server.Domain.ViastoreSrm.
   at OpenAccessRuntime.ObjectScope.GetMetaData(Type type)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.ObjectScope.CheckPersistentType(Type type)
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.ExtensionMethods.Extent[T](IObjectScope scope)
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.OpenAccessContext.GetAllCore[T]()
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.OpenAccessContext.GetAll[T]()
   at <Product>.Server.OpenAccess.Database.GetData[T]()
   at <Product>.<Customer>.Agv.Server.Manager.CheckViastoreOrder(IDatabaseConnection database) in C:\...\<Customer>\<Product>.<Customer>.Agv.Server\Manager.Viastore.cs:line 53
```

As you see, the `Exception` message is talking about connection id (what connection id?), configuration (what part of the configuration?), ... but most of all that enhancer gets back in the picture!

I have the impression that that enhancer is responsible for a lot of bad behaviour of my application. As this code is working without problems on the PC of a colleague, I believe this enhancer should be something outside of the development environment, but what?

How can I understand this matter? What is that enhancer? How do I configure (or get of) it? ... and most importantly, how can I make sure that it does not hinder my development any more?

Comment: Something which might be interesting: it happens regularly that it works ... once! When I try in Visual Studio 2017, Visual Studio 2019, 64-bit, 32-bit, ..., but when I try a second time it does not work anymore (even not after having done a "Clean").

Comment: ... but sometimes the "Clean" does work, it's enormously unstable.

Comment: Note: your error message mentions `Local\Temp_ptil_15736` doesn't exist but your next line says `\Local\Temp\_ptil_15736` does not exist. These don't match.

Comment: @DM: both (error message and my statement) mention the same directory: `...\Local\...`.

Comment: The `...\Local\...` part, yes. The final folder in the exception is called `Temp_ptil_15736` while the final folder in the statement is called `ptil_15736`. There's an extra `...\Temp\...` folder in the statement's path.

Comment: @DM: Oops, you are right. That seems to be caused by this website's display. I've turned the directory name into a code format in order to correct the display. Good catch!

Comment: Come on, guys. No one for the 200 points?

Comment: For Problem 2 check this link its may help you https://community.progress.com/s/article/Error-Type-is-enhanced-and-registered-but-not-available-from-the-database-class-meta-data

Comment: Tip: updating a problem with a superseding problem is OK where no answers have been supplied. In this case there were two AI answers, which were rightfully deleted. However I am not so sure that adding a supplementary question in order to skip the bounty delay is entirely right: if someone subsequently answers the first question, then there are now two competing questions, and marking one as "right" is not fair on good answers to the other question.

Comment: Thus, where you have no answers, I think it would be moderately better to edit the question and replace it with the new one, so that there is only one question to answer. I still wonder if it would be best to just ask a new question: the bounty delay is deliberate, and circumventing the rules here is generally frowned upon. If the bounty delay is regarded as unhelpful, perhaps we should get it removed?